# How to change App Drawer background to be less transparent

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, colors

How can I change the Ubuntu app drawer background color? or how can I decrease the blur effect, I don't want to see my wallpaper when I'm on the app drawer page.

**Too transparent.**

[image: large icons, wallpaper behind]

**I like this background.**

[image: dark background with Ubuntu MATE logo, app icons on top]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the app drawer background color can be changed by editing "user-shell" theme's .css file.

[image]

Please note that, with this answer, the background is not fully covered with the color we want, still edges, and the second page are transparent.

Take Backup of "user-shell" theme's .css file you are using.

> If you are not using custom user-shell theme, below are the default
>   files.
>
> for Ubuntu 18.04 `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`
>   for Ubuntu 19.04 & 19.10
>   `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

Open the file, find the below content.

```
/* App Vault/Grid */
.icon-grid {
  spacing: 30px;
  -shell-grid-horizontal-item-size: 136px;
  -shell-grid-vertical-item-size: 136px; }
  .icon-grid .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 96px; }
```

and change it like below, replace any color you want in place of rgba field.

```
/* App Vault/Grid */
.icon-grid {
  spacing: 30px;
  -shell-grid-horizontal-item-size: 136px;
  -shell-grid-vertical-item-size: 136px;
  background-color: rgba(71, 68, 68, 1); }
  .icon-grid .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 96px; }
```

Observe i have edited line number 1321 and added this under line number 1321
`background-color: rgba(71, 68, 68, 1); }`

Save the file, Close & Reboot or Logout and Login to see the Change.

[image]

[image]

I Use this website for choosing colors https://www.color-hex.com/
Control the transparency by the fourth value in `rgba(71, 68, 68, 1)`

[image]

Other Color with 0.5 transparency: `rgba(0, 165, 230, 0.5)`

[image]